# Keep Modification Date (filestamp) from a MTS video to a MP4 Video - Powershell Script

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell, video-conversion

I've been looking for a solution for this for sometime. The idea is simple: I've got old MTS videos that I have converted to mp4 videos through ffmpeg. Neither ffmpeg nor other alternatives such as Handbrake keep the timestamp of the original video. Exiftool [doesn't](https://superuser.com/questions/1422984/exiftool-command-for-batch-copying-mp4-metadata-from-files-to-files) work for my purpose either :(

I've tried to [use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250130/copy-file-creation-date-to-metadata-in-ffmpeg) the -map_metadata flag in ffmpeg [without success](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17948/ffmpeg-preserve-timecode-when-converting-mp4-to-mov), and also the 'touch -r' command, but again, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/437663/whats-an-elegant-way-to-copy-the-creation-and-modification-dates-of-a-file-to-a) doesn't do what I need. I've tried several solutions, and none of them seemed to work. Finally I found the "manual" solution, and I would like to create a Powershell script to automate everything.

As shown on the image, PowerShell [can](https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-touch-command-equivalent/#comments) effectively modify the CreationTime, LastAccessTime and LastWriteTime (the latter is the one I need!) of a file. What I'd like to automate is:

For every MTS file in a directory (and its subdirectories)

- Get the LastWriteTime of that MTS file
- Copy that to the LastWriteTime of the MP4 file that already exists on the folder

I don't know how to do that in Powershell, and I wonder if someone could answer this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, get all items, group them in pairs and set the LastWriteTime Property

```
# Get All .mp4 and .mts in folder, group them by basename, and iterate over all of them
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\jpast\Desktop\videos" | Where-Object Extension -in '.mp4','.MTS' | 
Group-Object BaseName | Where-Object Count -eq 2 | ForEach-Object {
    # Sort Ascending on Extension, mp4 is index 0 and mts is index 1
    $Objects = $_.Group | Sort-Object Extension
    $Objects[0].LastWriteTime = $Objects[1].LastWriteTime
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works if all the videos (MTS and MP4) are in the same folder, but I've got them in different folders, could that be done recursively?

Comment: @javipas Yes, you can either specify 2 paths in `Get-ChildItem "C:\somewhere\mp4path", "C:\somewhere\mtspath"` or you can do `Get-ChildItem C:\somewhere -Recurse` which will recursively search the folde. if you have everything in 2 folders, i'd go for option 1